# Finding functions of $y=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me to solve this, I don't understand even a scratch.

> Find all functions $y=f(x)$ with the property that a ray of light from the origin will be reflected by the graph of the function in the direction of positive $y$-axis.

Comment: To answer this question you need know how a ray of light is reflected off a curve. Hint: the angle of reflection (with regard to the tangent line) will be equal to the angle of incidence.

Comment: Recall Snell's Law (angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a parabola.

The "reflection property of a parabola" states that any ray of light coming from the focus of a parabola, when reflected off of the inside of the parabola, bounces in a direction parallel to the parabola's axis.

You can prove this by using the fact that, when a ray of light "hits" a flat surface, it bounces off in such a way that the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection:

[image]

However, when light bounces off of a curved surface at a point, it bounces off of the *tangent* to the surface at that point. Thus you must show that if a ray is drawn through the focus of a parabola, and the tangent to the parabola is drawn at the point at which the ray intersects the parabola, then the angle formed by the ray and the tangent is equal to the angle formed by the vertical line through the point of intersection and the tangent line through that point.

To make a long story short, all parabolas with foci at the origin satisfy this property, so if you find the general equation of such a parabola, then you're all set.

Comment: Very appreciated for your response. However, did you mean y=Cx^2 so I can make it parabola towards positive y-axis? If so, isn't there infinitely many solutions ? How can I make this question limited as it asked, I don't understand :D

Comment: No, not in the form $y=cx^2$. That type of parabola would not have a focus at $(0,0)$. And yes, there are infinitely many solutions, so you must find the general equation.

Comment: That's the problem itself, I really don't know how to find the general solution for this problem. My brain has literally stopped! But thank you for all of your help